# Localize Settings.Bundle in Xcode 5

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I can't be able to localize `Settings.Bundle` in `Xcode 5`.
When I create it only show the English localization.

I would like to add Italian localization but I have no ideas...

[image]